# Adding different images to a form according to name using if/else

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert image values into the html to replace the src according to the name so if the name for the templateName = Javascript I can make the src value = something like say (http://www.w3devcampus.com/wp-content/uploads/logoAndOther/logo_JavaScript.png) and do that for other categories as well using an if/else statement in javascript.

my script look like this but it has a few errors with the syntax

```
var imageChoosernator = function () {
        if (#templateName == "Javascript")
        {
            img = <img src="htp://www.w3devcampus.com/wp-content/uploads/logoAndOther/logo_JavaScript.png">;
        }
 `   }
```

Can someone guide me toward the proper solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery .prepend() method to replace the image src on loading the query into the page.
If in html you have given the id name as 'JavaScript' like-

```
div id="JavaScript"><img id="imgNew1"  src="oldImg1.png" />   
div id="templateName2"><img id="imgNew2"  src="oldImg2.png" />
```

To change the image source following can be used-

```
$('#templateName1').prepend('<img id="imgNew" src="newImg1.png" />')
$('#templateName2').prepend('<img id="imgNew" src="newImg2.png" />')
```

You need to read the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

To automatize the src change while creating intances of the same will go like-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var slideimages = new Array() // create new array to preload images
  slideimages[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
  slideimages[0].src = "firstImg.png" // set image object src property to an image's src, preloading that image in the process
  slideimages[1] = new Image()
  slideimages[1].src = "secondcarImg.png"
  slideimages[2] = new Image()
  slideimages[2].src = "thirdImg.png"
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="javascript:slidelink()"><img src="firstImg.img" id="slide" width=100 height=56 /></a>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  //variable that will increment through the images
  var step = 0
  var whichimage = 0
  function slideit(){
  //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
  if (!document.images)
  return
  document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
  whichimage = step
  if (step<2)
    step++
  else
    step=0

 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would work but I am trying to have it in an automated manner so that I can create new instances of an item called Javascript or another instance called SQL  and because the name of the element matches, then an image would be created and inserted as an avatar for the element.

Comment: do you want to automatize the source change, while creating instances of the same?

Comment: No. the instances are each different.

Comment: I have edited the above answer, how to do that with the instances of the same. Now you just need to create the instance of each different as I have done above.

Comment: Appreciate the help I will see if I can incorporate the technique.

Answer (score 1):

`#` in `#templateName` is wrong. Know your allowed variable characters.

`img = <img` the `<img` is an unstarted String. Know how to enclose values into String.

**`** <<< you cannot have such character floating around your code (hopefully just an edit typo).

---

Since you didn't showed most of your code, a fix would be something like:

```
var img = "";
var templateName = "Javascript";

function imageChoosernator () {
    if (templateName === "Javascript") { // remove unallowed #
        img = '<img src="js.png">';      // enclose into String
    } else {
        img = '<img src="someting.png">';
    }
    // Finally append img to element #imgContainer
    document.querySelector("#imgContainer").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", img );
}

imageChoosernator(); // Do the magic
```